# Spark read a parquet file(56MB) , get a df with two or more partitions

Tags: apache-spark

parquet file: (not set parquet.block.size when create this parquet file)

```
56.1 M 2021-06-17 10:32 /tmp/test/part-00002-ec3a9caa-a70e-4efe-8c5b-3f706f010610.c000.snappy.parquet
```

read the parquet file through spark:

1.spark-shell not set spark.default.parallelism

```
scala> spark.read.parquet("/tmp/test/part-00002-ec3a9caa-a70e-4efe-8c5b-3f706f010610.c000.snappy.parquet")
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [$id: bigint, $event: string ... 216 more fields]

scala> res1.rdd.getNumPartitions
res2: Int = 2
```

2.set spark.default.parallelism=25

```
scala> spark.read.parquet("/tmp/test/part-00002-ec3a9caa-a70e-4efe-8c5b-3f706f010610.c000.snappy.parquet").rdd.getNumPartitions
res0: Int = 15
```

Q:

```
1.What is relation between the number of df partitions and the spark.default.parallelism ?
```

spark: 2.4.0.7.1.1.0-565

Comment: I think the number of partition is related to parquet block size and the number of parquet file ,but it doesn't seem to be correct .

Comment: parquet file was created through df.write.save, and not set parquet.block.size